# flink 1.15 planner loader ArithemeticUtils NoClassDefFoundError issue

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

when using flink 1.15 with the new planner loader module with provided scope, I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError for ArithmeticUtils class, I explicitly imported it but it hasn't worked. Can Anyone Help here, not able to fix this issue. Below is the stacktrace and pom attached. Working with new flink 1.15 version

```
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.utils.FlinkRelOptUtil$.mergeMiniBatchInterval(FlinkRelOptUtil.scala:439)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.rules.physical.stream.MiniBatchIntervalInferRule.onMatch(MiniBatchIntervalInferRule.scala:81)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.AbstractRelOptPlanner.fireRule(AbstractRelOptPlanner.java:333)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.applyRule(HepPlanner.java:542)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.applyRules(HepPlanner.java:407)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.executeInstruction(HepPlanner.java:243)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepInstruction$RuleInstance.execute(HepInstruction.java:127)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.executeProgram(HepPlanner.java:202)
    at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.findBestExp(HepPlanner.java:189)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkHepProgram.optimize(FlinkHepProgram.scala:69)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkHepRuleSetProgram.optimize(FlinkHepRuleSetProgram.scala:87)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.$anonfun$optimize$2(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:63)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:154)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.$anonfun$optimize$1(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:60)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.$anonfun$optimize$1$adapted(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:154)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkGroupProgram.optimize(FlinkGroupProgram.scala:55)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkChainedProgram.$anonfun$optimize$1(FlinkChainedProgram.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.$anonfun$foldLeft$1$adapted(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:156)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.foldLeft$(TraversableOnce.scala:154)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.foldLeft(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.program.FlinkChainedProgram.optimize(FlinkChainedProgram.scala:58)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.optimizeTree(StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:164)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.optimizeBlock(StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:118)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.$anonfun$doOptimize$2(StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:89)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.$anonfun$doOptimize$2$adapted(StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:89)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:58)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.doOptimize(StreamCommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:89)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.optimize.CommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.optimize(CommonSubGraphBasedOptimizer.scala:77)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.optimize(PlannerBase.scala:303)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translate(PlannerBase.scala:179)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.translate(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1656)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.executeInternal(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:782)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.StatementSetImpl.execute(StatementSetImpl.java:108)
    at com.dream11.data.spaas.pipeline.DataPipeline.execute(DataPipeline.scala:25)
    at com.dream11.data.spaas.jobs.AllEventsStreamverse$.delayedEndpoint$com$dream11$data$spaas$jobs$AllEventsStreamverse$1(AllEventsStreamverse.scala:76)
    at com.dream11.data.spaas.jobs.AllEventsStreamverse$delayedInit$body.apply(AllEventsStreamverse.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at com.dream11.data.spaas.jobs.AllEventsStreamverse$.main(AllEventsStreamverse.scala:8)
    at com.dream11.data.spaas.jobs.AllEventsStreamverse.main(AllEventsStreamverse.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.util.ArithmeticUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at org.apache.flink.core.classloading.ComponentClassLoader.loadClassFromComponentOnly(ComponentClassLoader.java:149)
    at org.apache.flink.core.classloading.ComponentClassLoader.loadClass(ComponentClassLoader.java:112)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    ... 71 more
```

My Pom

````
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test.d</groupId>
  <artifactId>data</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>data</name>

  <url>https://github.com/ff/data</url>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>data-core</module>
    <module>data-service</module>
    <module>data-infer-service</module>
  </modules>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jitpack.io</id>
      <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.7.0.1746</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
    <git-code-format-maven-plugin.version>2.7</git-code-format-maven-plugin.version>
    <flink.version>1.15.0</flink.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.version>2.12.7</scala.version>
    <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.8.3</jacoco.version>
    <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.7.0.1746</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.language>scala</sonar.language>
    <scala_maven_plugin.version>4.5.2</scala_maven_plugin.version>
    <flink.scope>provided</flink.scope>
    <scala.version.binary>2.12</scala.version.binary>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
      <artifactId>json4s-native_${scala.version.binary}</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.saasquatch</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-schema-inferrer</artifactId>
      <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-runtime-web</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-table-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-connector-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.version.binary}</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-table-api-scala_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-table-planner-loader</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-table-api-scala-bridge_${scala.version.binary}</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-json</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-csv</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-sql-avro-confluent-registry</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-s3-fs-presto</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>${flink.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-metrics-dropwizard</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-statebackend-rocksdb</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-shaded-guava</artifactId>
      <version>30.1.1-jre-15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.49</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
      <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.19.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>de-flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>shaded-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
      <artifactId>config</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.argparse4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>argparse4j</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.asynchttpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>async-http-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java</artifactId>
      <version>${flink.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
      <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
      <version>1.15.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
      <version>1.49</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- my plugins -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.cosium.code</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-code-format-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${git-code-format-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install-formatter-hook</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-hooks</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>validate-code-format</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>validate-code-format</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <googleJavaFormatOptions>
            <fixImportsOnly>false</fixImportsOnly>
            <skipSortingImports>false</skipSortingImports>
            <skipRemovingUnusedImports>false</skipRemovingUnusedImports>
          </googleJavaFormatOptions>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.s</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <outputFile>
                ${project.basedir}/target/jars/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar
              </outputFile>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
          <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
          <output>file</output>
          <append>true</append>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>*MethodAccess</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
              <goal>report-integration</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

</project>```
````

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28239 which will be resolved in Flink 1.15.2